# How can I print a data column with tshark as ascii instead of hex?

Tags: networking, wireshark, tshark

While this -

> tshark -r .pcap -T fields -e data

outputs hex, I didn't find a way to decode this column as ascii with tshark. Is it possible?

Comment: So `tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e data.text` is working for data over udp, but not for data over tcp. help?

Comment: it will work for undissected data

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e data.text
```

Ref: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/d/data.html